# Java Project in svn, combine it with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

In my svn i have an oldschool java project.

Now i want to check it out in eclipse and combine it with Maven.

How can i do this?
My way: 
1.) Checkout the project
2.) manually create all folders and pom.xml

Is this how i do this, or is there another way?

Comment: What build system the "oldschool" project uses might be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually think that it will be easier to create a new Maven project in Eclipse and then check out your artifacts from SVN into src/main/java and src/test/java folders. Especially if you're using M2E maven plugin for Eclipse, i'd let it create a directory structure and default pom.xml.

Comment: mh sorry, but how do i checkout the svnproject into another project after i already created the maven project locally?

Comment: I thought you will check out only subtrees that contain source files and resources of your existing project from svn into corresponding dirs. You will have to define all the dependencies in pom file anyway, so the .project and .classpath will be of no use to you anyway.

Comment: yes sure thats what i want to do... but i dont find any option how i can do this... i can just check it out in my workspace location, but not in any project?

Comment: you should be able to go to your new maven project folder and do smth like: "svn checkout file_or_http://your_repo_url/your_proejct/java_src src/main/java" and "svn checkout file_or_http://your_repo_url/your_proejct/java_resources src/main/resources"